# center of Raphael triangle

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Let's say I need to put a text in the middle of the area of a triangle.
I can calculate the coordinates of the triangle's center using getBBox():

```
var triangle = "M0,0 L100,0 100,50 z";
var BBox = paper.path(triangle).getBBox();
var middle;
middle.x = BBox.x + BBox.width/2;
middle.y = BBox.y + BBox.height/2;
```

This results in the coordinates (50, 25) which are always on the long side of the triangle.
How can I make sure the calculated "middle" is *inside* the triangle?

The correct coordinates should be approximately: (75, 25).

The code should of course be independent of this particular example, it should work for any kind of shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some more research in the topic, and following an advice from another list I got here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid

There is an algorithm there to calculate the centroid of an irregular polygon, which I have translated into this code:

```
function getCentroid(path) {
    var x = new Array(11);
    var y = new Array(11);
    var asum = 0, cxsum = 0, cysum = 0;
    var totlength = path.getTotalLength();
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        var location = path.getPointAtLength(i*totlength/10);
        x[i] = location.x;
        y[i] = location.y;

        if (i > 0) {
            asum += x[i - 1]*y[i] - x[i]*y[i - 1];
            cxsum += (x[i - 1] + x[i])*(x[i - 1]*y[i] - x[i]*y[i - 1]);
            cysum += (y[i - 1] + y[i])*(x[i - 1]*y[i] - x[i]*y[i - 1]);
        }
    }

    return({x: (1/(3*asum))*cxsum, y: (1/(3*asum))*cysum});

}
```

It's basically an approximation of any path by 10 points (the 11th is equal to the starting point), and the function returns, for that triangle, the coordinates:

```
Object {x: 65.32077336966377, y: 16.33111549955705}
```

I've tested it with many other shapes, and it works pretty good.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will calculate the center of any polygon by averaging the vertices.

```js
var paper = Raphael(0,0, 320, 200);

var triangle = "M0,0 L100,0 100,50 z";
var tri = paper.path(triangle);
tri.attr('fill', 'blue');

var center = raphaelPathCenter( tri );
var circle = paper.circle( center.x, center.y, 5);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");


function raphaelPathCenter( path ) {
 
  path.getBBox(); // forces path to be traced so realPath is not null.
  
  var vertices = parseSVGVertices( path.realPath );
  
  var center = vertices.reduce( function(prev,cur) {
      return { x: prev.x + cur.x, y: prev.y + cur.y }
    }, {x:0, y:0} );
  
  center.x /= vertices.length;
  center.y /= vertices.length;

  return center;
}

function parseSVGVertices( svgPath )
{
  var vertices = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < svgPath.length; i ++ )
  {    
    var vertex = svgPath[i];
    
    if ( "ML".indexOf( vertex[0] ) > -1 ) // check SVG command
        vertices.push( { x: vertex[1], y: vertex[2] } );
  }  
  return vertices;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael-min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<pre id='output'></pre>
```

However there are [a few more triangle centers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center#Some_well-known_triangle_centers) to choose from.

Comment: This solution is smart, but I was looking for something related to SVG, and more precisely to Raphael.js
Moreover, it should work for _any_ kind of shape, a triangle was just an example to exemplify the problem...

Comment: Well, vector coordinates are related to SVG; your code won't run because a string doesn't have a `getBBox()` method ;-) But, there is no such formula for any kind of shape; you have to take into consideration what kind of center you want, which you didn't specify, and whether the shape is convex or concave. For a convex shape, averaging the vertices will always be inside the shape; not so for concave shapes.

Comment: Oh, you're right... I was too quick to post the code. The correct line, of course, is:
    var BBox = paper.path(triangle).getBBox();
It's just an irregular polygon. Not convex, not concave, just irregular.

Comment: I don't think you follow. Look [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/concave.html); see the bottom right polygon? That one is concave. If you average the coordinates, the center may just fall within the polygon surface. But as soon as the top left or top right vertex is a little higher, the center will not be inside the polygon surface.

Comment: Updated the answer. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works very well with the triangle, but not with other shapes, unfortunately. I've added an answer with an algorithm found on Wikipedia.

Comment: Oh, and... btw Raphael actually does have a function to obtain the bounding box of a path string. It is: paper.pathBbox()